# Install own kernel in CentOS. Is that possible?

Tags: centos, kernel, dracut

So I'm having a customized kernel(.deb packages).

And like I wanna apply kernel on CentOS. Is this possible?

Over the internet found out that it's possible with "dracut tool", but how?

Or I should recompile the kernel, especially for CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

Take what ever patches where applied to build your custom kernel and apply them to the Centos Kernel source and rebuild.

Do not try and get a Debian packaged kernel to boot a CentOS system